# Dynamics 365 connector for outlook 365 calendar and contacts

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

I need to create a connector between Dynamics 365 CRM and Outlook 365 to automatically import contacts and events when added.

I try to create a connector in power automate but I can't  find the entity of the calendar in Dynamics...
I see that is there also a configuration in dynamics but i think is not working for me

Comment: Why are you looking for a calendar? If you want to sync your appointments - there is an appointment entity for it.

Comment: I need to sync the appointment and the contacts from office, did u think i just need to sync the appointment entity? and i need to do it with power automate or what?

Comment: I believe that should be enough.

Comment: sorry but howi can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls explore the [Dynamics 365 App for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/dynamics365/outlook-app/overview?WT.mc_id=5004422).

- Link email messages, meetings, and appointments to a row in your app. For example, link an email message to a specific account, opportunity, or case.
- View information in the context of an email message, meeting, or appointment.
- Synchronize contacts and related information so that Exchange and your app is always up to date.
- Add email templates, knowledge articles, and sales literature when you create an email message or set up a meeting.

Comment: I need to create a custom connector that's why

Comment: This was true, but as you see i got problems connecting to the CRM ...have you ever had this problem?